# I want split the comma seperate value then insert every value to another table in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

table users as below

```
--------------------
portal_id | user_id
1     | 100
1     | 101 
1     | 102
1     | 103
---------------------

SELECT group_concat(user_id) as toUserIds FROM users where portal_id=1;
```

after am getting in toUserIds is 100,101,102,103

after i want insert doc_user_xref table as below(same doc id with different user id )

```
insert into doc_user_xref(doc_id,user_id)values(5211,100);
insert into doc_user_xref(doc_id,user_id)values(5211,101); 
insert into doc_user_xref(doc_id,user_id)values(5211,102);
insert into doc_user_xref(doc_id,user_id)values(5211,103);
```

In above insert value i need loop or iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `GROUP_CONCAT()`, just use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO doc_user_xref
  (doc_id, user_id)
SELECT 5211, user_id
FROM   users
WHERE  portal_id = 1
```

Comment: I want to use in many place for above question which i have attached table and query is simplified model not exact full model. i want loop or iterator model eggyal.

Comment: @KrishnaS: SQL is not really designed for working with "loops" and "iterators" - it is designed for working with sets.  Almost any operation you are likely to perform on your data, no matter how complicated, can be concisely expressed using powerful set operations in SQL.  This answer is the correct solution to the problem as you have asked it.  If your actual problem is more complicated, you will need to explain why it is that this solution is not applicable in order that people can help you to find the correct SQL set operation to solve it.

Comment: First i Thank you, i have confuse following query,"INSERT INTO doc_user_xref (doc_id, user_id)SELECT docId , user_id FROM   users WHERE  portal_id = 1" the docId is already declared and fetch the data from another table,so am using select to the users table not having docId column, so how am implement it.

Comment: Thanks,you query working now. i have change my query entirely.